# Possible to use Import-CSV cmd without defining specific filename?

Tags: powershell, csv, import

So in my current scenario I am moving a .csv file to a location where I want to execute a script to parse the .csv, removing specific data, and creating a new file with only that extracted data.

My code is fine and its all working as I want.

However now I'm running through another set of UAT while using data files from production. These .csv files come to us each day, datestamped.

I've written my script initially with a text.csv, and wish to automate this script on a schedule. However now looks I need to define the csv file each time? This is not feasible.

Is it possible to use the import-csv cmdlet to have it just load the csv file it sees in the folder?

Here is my code

```
Import-Csv "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\" |Where 
{$_.SITEID -like "7*"} | Select 
SITEID,DATE,REVENUECENTER,OVERGROUP,UNITS,PRICE,NETT,VATRATE,VAT,GROSS | 
ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"',""} |Out-File "\\pg-
app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\sales_$(get-date -f 
yyyy_MM_dd)_NI.csv" -fo -en ascii
```

This is returning an error, even with just one CSV file in the folder.
    SALES_27062017_090019.csv

There should only ever be one file present here, so wondering if its possible to have powershell just load the csv file, regardless of the filenamebeing defined?

I've tried

```
Import-Csv "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\*.csv"
```

And while it gave me a generated output file, was nothing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do:

```
(Get-ChildItem "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\*.csv").FullName | Import-Csv
```

Because `Get-ChildItem` accepts wildcard parameters for its `-Path` parameter.

Your attempt of:

```
Import-Csv "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\*.csv"
```

Doesn't work because the `-Path` parameter of `Import-CSV` does not accept wildcard characters.

If you want to make sure you only ever get 1 CSV returned you could do:

```
(Get-ChildItem "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\*.csv" | Select -First 1).FullName | Import-Csv
```

Comment: This site is the gift that keeps on giving. Thanks a million Mark, worked perfectly.

Comment: Pretty sure Import-CSV binds values by parameter so `GCI -Path $path | Import-CSV` would work as well as  `GCI -Path $path | Select -First 
 1 | Import-CSV`

Comment: `get-childitem -path *.csv | Import-CSV` returns:
Import-CSV : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

`Import-CSV` *can*, in fact, handle importing from multiple CSVs, but does not have any wildcard processing. So, you need to generate the list of CSVs - which may include only a single CSV - some other way:

```
Import-CSV ((Get-ChildItem -Path "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\*.csv").FullName)
```

should work, as should the solution proposed by @MarkWragg

Comment: I amended my answer to pull the `FullName` property explictly as when I tested it didn't know whether to bind it to Path or LiteralPath. Your solution is arguably better as it makes the parameter of -Path explicit (by position at least).

Comment: The default is to pass a string to `Get-ChildItem` as `-Path`, which is good, since I believe that using `-LiteralPath` also prevents expansion of wildcards. You make a good point about `$_.FullName`, because there's no assurance that the script is running in the same directory as the CSVs are located. I've amended my answer to accommodate that.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, your solution works perfectly along with Marks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys, appreciate the help.

So here is my final cut that is achieving what I want

```
(Get-ChildItem "\\pg-app05\Micros\Scripted Data 
Extraction\Sales\*.csv").FullName | Import-Csv |Where {$_.SITEID -like "7*"} 
| Select 
SITEID,DATE,REVENUECENTER,OVERGROUP,UNITS,PRICE,NETT,VATRATE,VAT,GROSS | 
ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"',""} |Out-File "\\pg-
app05\Micros\Scripted Data Extraction\Sales\sales_$(get-date -f 
yyyy_MM_dd)_NI.csv" -fo -en ascii
```

I'm now getting a generated outfile that contains the parsed data I need. On with more testing!